# What tool should I use to fetch HTTP header of a remote web server?

Tags: http, curl

I am basically looking for something similar but simpler tool like cURL that fetches http header without the body. Not interested downloading the body. Noticed cURL seems to download the body and consumes unnecessary bandwidth for my need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the `-I` flag to curl to make it issue a `HEAD` request, i.e., just the headers.

(not guaranteed to be exactly the same, but is supposed to be)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the libcurl library, the `curl_easy_setopt()` function has a `CURLOPT_NOBODY` option available, which causes libcurl to send a `HEAD` request to download just the headers, instead of a `GET` request to download the entire data.